# What is a more formal way to say, "all hands on deck"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice, synonyms, idiom-request

I want to convey that there is a lot to do, and that everyone's help (who is willing) is needed. I do not think that "all hands on deck" is very formal?

Comment: How formal do you want to be? My boss at work often says 'It's a case of all hands to the pump today, folks'.

Comment: And the staff say 'More like all noses to the grindstone'.